# My UserForm doesnt give an Output (GoogleSheets)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am very new to google sheets and tryed to use an Userform to fill in my Sheets. But every time, i click submit it just freezes and nothing more happends...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LdDIMvWpVkj5rom2fHV25FtYvbOcnKr4cZF84nITYQ/edit?usp=sharing

And the code:
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price" class="form-label">price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" >Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    <script>

      function afterButtonClicked(){
        var item = document.getElementById("name");
        var price = document.getElementById("price");
        
        google.script.run.addnewrow(name,price);
      }
        document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
    <script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here are my functions:

```
function addnewRow(nameprice) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  ws.appendRow([name,price]);
 
}
```

I dont know if its important, but here is the cutom menu:

```
function loadForm() {

  const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("uform");
  const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate();

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);
  
}


function createMenu(){

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu("Meine Forms");
  menu.addItem("Show UserForm","loadForm");
  menu.addToUi();

}

function onOpen(){
  createMenu();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your are missing a comma in `function addnewRow(nameprice) {`.  Should be `function addnewRow(name,price) {`

Comment: Thank you I changed it, but it did not solve the Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few modification in your code:-

1. In HTML file you've syntax error, you didn't used `</script>`.
2. You're passing wrong variable as a argument in `addnewRow` while running  it through `google.script.run`.
3. You're trying to run function which actually doesn't exist in server-side.
4. Parameter in `addnewRow` function is missing comma `,` in server-side.
5. Sheet you're trying to access in `ss.getSheetByName("Results")` doesn't exist.

Do following modifications in `<script>` tag of client side code(HTML File):-

```
    <script>

       function afterButtonClicked(){

        var item = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        google.script.run.addnewRow(item,price);
      }
        document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
    </script>
```

**And replace this :-**

```
function addnewRow(nameprice) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  ws.appendRow([name,price]);     
}
```

**with this :-**

```
function addnewRow(name,price) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  ws.appendRow([name,price]); 
}
```

and change/add the sheet name as `Result` in Spreadsheet.